Stable diffusion: AttributeError: module 'jax.random' has no attribute 'KeyArray'
When I run the stable diffusion on colab  https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/diffusers/stable_diffusion.ipynb
with no modification, it fails on the line
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline 
The error log is
AttributeError: module 'jax.random' has no attribute 'KeyArray'
How can I fix this or any clue ?
The import should work, the ipynb should run with no error.

jax.random.KeyArray was deprecated in JAX v0.4.16 and removed in JAX v0.4.24. Given this, it sounds like the HuggingFace stable diffusion code only works JAX v0.4.23 or earlier.
You can install JAX v0.4.23 with GPU support like this:
pip install "jax[cuda12_pip]==0.4.23" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html

or, if you prefer targeting a local CUDA installation, like this:
pip install "jax[cuda12_local]==0.4.23" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html

For more information on GPU installation, see JAX Installation: NVIDIA GPU.
From the colab tutorial, update the second segment into:
!pip install "jax[cuda12_local]==0.4.23" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
!pip install diffusers==0.11.1
!pip install transformers scipy ftfy accelerate


In the end, we need to downgrade the jax,
Try each from the lateset to ealier, and luckily it works for
jax==0.4.23 jaxlib==0.4.23


This jaxlib version is not CUDA enabled.
How can install these versions of jax and jaxlib if we want the jaxlib to be cuda 12 enabled 12.2?
Because it does not make sense to use colab without gpu for stable diffusion projects....

@hunsnowboarder update, does it still stand true? I just had the same error and while installing 0.4.23 atleast makes my project run on colab, it is slow on T4 but it does show "GPU usage" 10GB onwards, and it keeps growing as it should, I am a newbie here so I dont understand whether its working as it should.

@SKB_BGPL - strange..I got an error when I tried to run it on GPU machine... and I solved my problem by using the lates diffusion model so there was no more conflict with the jax libraries

# Change this
# !pip install diffusers==0.11.1

# To just
!pip install diffusers 

If you've already run pip install in your Colab runtime, you'll need to either disconnect and open a new runtime (my recommendation) or use  --upgrade.
Diffusers v0.11.1 is now over 18 months old, and the notebook works with current v0.29.0 without any other changes. Instead of using an old version of diffusers, requiring an old version of jax, we can use the latest versions.
